# ¿Como recorrer un regristro de una query, y pasar los valores que se van obteniendo como parametro a otro Store Procedure en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente Store Procedure:

```
        DELIMITER $$

        USE `open_bd`$$

        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `LlamarEjemplo`$$

        CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `LlamarLibroCompras_ListarMesPeriodo`(IN rutempresaC VARCHAR(10),IN periodoC INT, IN mesC INT)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE c_noint INT(12) ;
            DECLARE done     TINYINT DEFAULT 0; 
            DECLARE cursor_ejemplo CURSOR FOR
            SELECT noint FROM lcomp WHERE periodo=periodoC AND mes=mesC AND rutempresa=rutempresaC; 
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        OPEN cursor_ejemplo;
        loop1:LOOP

               FETCH cursor_ejemplo INTO c_noint;
                   IF done THEN
                LEAVE loop1;
               END IF;
               IF done=1 THEN
              LEAVE loop1;
               ELSE 
              CALL Ejemplo_parametros(rutempresaC,periodoC, mesC,c_noint);       
               END IF; 
        END LOOP loop1;
        CLOSE cursor_ejemplo;

 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Lo que deseo, es que a medida vaya recorriendo la fila de la query declarada en el cursor cursor_ejemplo, pueda ir enviando el valor noint de la tabla lcomp. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer, e ir almacenarlo en una variable de cursor c_noint,  y a medida que se avance recorriendo la fila de la tabla, se le vaya enviando el resultado como parametro a Ejemplo_parametros. Pero resulta que no me funciona, ya que me envía solo un registro de la tabla.

me gustaría saber como poder hacer tal objetivo, enviando como parámetro los valores que se van recorriendo en el registro de la tabla.

Comment: Tengo una fuerte sospecha que no deberías estar usando un cursor aquí.  Creo que te estás complicando mucho. ¿Qué estás tratando de hacer en realidad? ¿Qué hace tu stored procedure?

Comment: Lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es al procedure Ejemplo_parametros, enviarle el c_noint de uno por uno. El procedure que llamo, no importa no lo que hace, solo necesito saber como enviarle los registros de uno por uno al recorrer la fila de la query

Comment: ¿Por qué le agregastes la etiqueta SQL Server otra vez si la pregunta no tiene que ver con esa base de datos?

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, aparte que aparentemente no copiastes bien el código, porque falta un punto y coma por allí, y no incluistes el final del stored procedure... pero aparte de eso, debería funcionar correctamente. Lo mejor sería que incluyas [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), tal vez usando un sitio como http://rextester.com o algo similar, para que podamos reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Pero lo que mas importa, era saber como hacer el recorrido, y asignarlo, bastaba con un ejemplo simple, puse el codigo como un ejemplo no mas que estaba probando

Answer (score -2):

Hola puedes enviarle valores en el select, pero seria llamando a una función en vez de un store , ya dentro de esta función llamada Ejemplo_parametros  mandas a llamar el store con los mismos parametros.

```
SELECT
 CASE noint
 WHEN 1 THEN 
 Ejemplo_parametros(rutempresaC,periodoC, mesC,c_noint)
 when 0 then
  '' end 
 FROM lcomp WHERE periodo=periodoC AND mes=mesC AND rutempresa=rutempresaC;
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

saludos.

Comment: Lamentablemente no se puede hacer así de simple, ya que para eso, debo crear una tabla temporal, e ir insertando los datos a medida que los encuentros, esa sería la única forma que veo.